# Prevent editors from inserting web parts

Tags: web-part, security, security-trimming

Is it possible to restrict editors from inserting web parts anywhere on a SharePoint 2010 publishing page? This [article](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/disable-inserting-web-parts-sharepoint-2010-rich-text-editor/) talks about disabling it for certain parts of the page or hiding the Ribbon element. Is this the only solution? We can't edit permissions to disable this functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give the editor Design pemissions or ensure the permissions being used by that group do not have these options checked.
[image: add web part options]

Comment: Thanks, PirateEric. I'd never seen those settings. For those wondering where these are, from the root of your site collection, you'd go to Site Actions > Site Permissions > Permission Levels (from the Ribbon) > Click on one of the items, such as "Contribute", to see what fine-grained control you have. But can the users still be able to edit the HTML of the pages, which we want them to be able to do?

Comment: A followup: For publishing pages, can Contribute users edit the content of the pages but not be able to insert web parts?

Comment: I think that depends.  If the web part content is being pulled in from a list, then they just need edit permissions on the list where the content is derived.  If they have to edit content editor web parts or other content areas, then this might not work.  An event receiver or client side solution might be needed to intercept the add web part action and cancel their request.

Comment: Hm. That makes it tricky. We have a page layout in a publishing site with Page Content area and web part zones.